# Character and message count for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, textbox, word-count

anyone have any idea how to increase a label to 2(or more) messages whenever there are 160 characters or more in a text box?

Comment: Use `JavaScript/jQuery` code.

Comment: May I know how? I use JavaScript code but it only work in IE, not able to work in firefox

Comment: What do you mean by 2 or more messages?

Comment: Currently I'm not using Javascript. I'm using SKMControl from ( http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/103107-1.aspx ). This can only count the total character and words but not able to count the number of message

Comment: For example, like our phone. Every time when the character exceed 160, the total message became 2. 320, 3 messages. I wanna make it a label that will change when there are more than 160 characters.

Answer (score 3):

Create an Event to change the text in the textbox, calculate number of characters there. Then check for the required characters to reach the limit, and increase the label text value as shown below,

```
private void txtSearchMember_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (txtSearchMember.Text.Length >= 160)
        {
                lblMessageCount.Text = 1; // Increase count with simple maths
        }
    }
```